# Processing return int from loadStrings and use the data of the array for objects

Tags: processing

As a beginner in programming and learning Processing,I am really stuck on this. Probably as simple as it can be but I don't see it anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```java
int geefCijfer (int[] cijfer1) {
  String [] cijfers =loadStrings("cijfers_klein.txt");
  int [] cijfer = new int [cijfers.length];
  for (int i = 0; i< cijfers.length; i++) {
    cijfer[i] = int(cijfers[i]);
    println(cijfer);
  } 
  return cijfer;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you expect this code to do? What does it do instead? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please try to be more specific. Include in your question what you expect the code to do, what it does instead, and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

That being said, I copied your code into my Processing editor and I get a compiler error on this line:

```java
return cijfer;
```

The error says:

```java
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
```

This is happening because you're returning `cijfer`, which is an `int[]` type, but you've declared your function to return an `int`. You either need to change what you're returning, or change the return type of the function. My guess is you just want to change the return type:

```java
int[] geefCijfer (int[] cijfer1) {
```

This gets rid of the error, but you'll still have a warning because you never use the `cijfer1` variable. That won't prevent you from running your code, but it's probably something you want to think harder about.

Also note that instead of manually converting each index of the array, you can pass the whole array into the `int()` function:

```java
String [] cijfers =loadStrings("cijfers_klein.txt");
int [] cijfer = int(cijfers);
```